# rust vim plugin file type detection not working

Tags: vim

I installed the rust.vim plugin in ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start. If I open a file called main.rs and type 
:scriptnames, here is the output

`

```
 1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
  9: ~/.vim/plugin/ScrollColor.vim
 10: ~/.vim/plugin/color_sample_pack.vim
 11: ~/.vim/plugin/mimicpak.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 23: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/plugin/cargo.vim
 24: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/plugin/rust.vim
 25: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/ftdetect/rust.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/hercules.vim
```

`

If I type :set ft, here is the output:

```
filetype=hercules
```

Output of :autocmd filetypedetect pertaining to hercules:

```
*.vc      setf hercules
*.ev      setf hercules
*.rs      setf hercules
*.sum     setf hercules
*.errsum  setf hercules
```

There is no lines pertaining to rust

Output of :20verbose e main.rs pertaining to hercules:

```
Executing BufRead Auto commands for "*.rs"
autocommand setf hercules
line 0: setf hercules
```

followed by a bunch of lines about the formatting of hercuels.

```
Searching for "/.vim/ftplugin/hercules.vim"
Searching for "/.vim/ftplugin/hercules_*.vim"
Searching for "/.vim/ftplugin/hercules/*.vim"
Searching for "/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/ftplugin/hercules.vim"
Searching for "/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/ftplugin/hercules_*.vim"
Searching for "/.vim/pack/plugins/start/rust.vim/ftplugin/hercules/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin/hercules.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin/hercules_*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin/hercules/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/hercules.vim"
```

This block of Searching for gets repeated later as well. At the very end of the output is this:

```
 Executing BufRead Auto commands for "*.rs"
autocommand setf rust
line 0: setf rust
Executing BufEnter Auto commands for "*"
autocommand sil call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
line 0: sil call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
```

Can anybody tell me how to make vim read the filetype as rust instead of hercules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `:autocmd filetypedetect`. For me (Vim 8.1.744), the following patterns apply to `hercules` / `rust`. (I don't know what the rust.vim plugin does, but at least filetype detection, plugin, and syntax already ship with Vim itself.)

```
*.vc      setf hercules
*.ev      setf hercules
*.sum     setf hercules
*.errsum  setf hercules
[...]
*.rs      setf rust
```

For you, the output presumably is different. You need to find out where the wrong pattern comes from. One way is observing all commands executed when opening the file:

```
:20verbose e main.rs
```

If the hercules filetype has precedence over the rust one (as seems to be the case based on your edits), you either have to remove the hercules one (I wonder where that `*.rs` glob comes from, even my old Vim 7.4 doesn't have it), or define an override as described in [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype): *A. If you want to overrule all default file type checks.* That is, create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/rust.vim` with:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.rs      set filetype=rust
```

Note the difference: `:set filetype=` is unconditional setting, whereas the [`:setf`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetf) used by the default rules only sets if it isn't defined yet (so hercules, coming first, wins for you so far).

Comment: Added output of :20verbose e main.rs and :autocmd filetypedetect to question

Comment: So it seems that the hercules one wins; hard to say where that comes from, so I've added instructions how to override it.